# SSL with Relative Path on JSP (Basic)

Tags: jsp, ssl, relative-path, servlet-filters, relative-url

How do I get SSL to work with relative paths on a JSP page.  Regardless of whether I'm calling a servlet in a form or just linking to a separate page, is there a way to guarantee that the paths "/foo.do", or "/foo.jsp" will automatically go to https://www.mydomain.com/foo.do?

The options I see are just hard-coding the path (not desirable) or using a filter to re-write the url in transit.  However, I searched online and could not really find an existing servlet for this function, leading me to believe it isn't the best approach.

Comment: Do you mean that you want all URLs to be rewritten with an "https" scheme, without regard to whether the URL appears in a page that was served by http or https?

Comment: I think I might have a basic misunderstanding of the concept... I don't want to re-write all urls, I just want some pages to be served as https, and I don't know how to do that with relative paths.